# Nested image link has no width, all parent element sizes defined

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've broken a grid. For some reason, nesting a link has made it unreachable by the rest of the css code. It's a long sliver down the left side of the grid element. All the parent elements have defined sizes, so that's not it. Here's the HTML:

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 15%;
    column-gap: 3%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 9%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 9%);
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    padding-left: 12%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

main a {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: 3%; 
    margin-bottom: 40%;
    margin-top: 60%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#A {
    background: url('Buttons/button.png') no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
   <div>
       <a href="A.html" id="A"></a>
       <p> A </p>
   </div>
</main>
```

For some reason, adding another grid inside the grid element fixed it (but the link was then too small, and also that seems like a hack job). (div is also defined but just for scaling so I didn't add it.) main a is able to control the other links, but no combination of selectors fixes the one in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `<a>` tag to correctly inherit the widths of its parent(s), you need to turn it into a block-level element by giving it `display: block`. This is because the `<a>` tag is `inline` by default, which means that it won't accept a `width` or `height` value (even if it's inherited).

I've replaced the image to show this working in the following:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 15%;
  column-gap: 3%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 9%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 9%);
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 40%;
  margin-top: 60%;
  width: 90%;
  padding-bottom: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#A {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/100') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <a href="A.html" id="A"></a>
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleperson